# Error during ubuntu upgrade (errors were encountered while processing)

Tags: ubuntu, apt, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade my ubuntu from 11.10 to 14.10 but I got this error message when I ran

```
sudo apt-get -f install

errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/udev-204-5ubuntu20.10_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/libgtk2.0-0_2.24.23-0ubuntu1.1-i386.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/libgtk2.0-0_2.24.23-0ubuntu1.1-amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/gnome-themes-standard_3.10.0-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

How could I solve the problem?